# Como inserir objetos iguais ou lista de objetos no MongoDB?

Tags: delphi, mongodb, nosql, object-pascal

Exemplo, tenho o seguinte JSON:

```
{
    Casa:'b32',
    integrantes:{
        pessoa: 'joao',
        pessoa: 'Maria',
        pessoa: 'Daniel'
    }
}
```

Ao inserir no banco de dados ele fica desta maneira.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente é sobrescrito. Atualmente faço essa inserção pelo Delphi(), mas ocorre o mesmo no console do próprio MongoDB;

No Delphi:

```
oDoc: TMongoDocument;
oDoc.BeginObject('doc').Append(stringJson).EndObject;
collection.Insert(oDoc);
```

Existe alguma maneira de inserir estes objetos duplicados no Json? Não encontrei nada na documentação do Mongo sobre essa duplicidade ou inserção dessa maneira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o que você quer fazer é incluir um array do objeto pessoa, da forma que fez está incluindo uma propriedade/atributo pessoa e realmente só é possível ter uma propriedade com o mesmo nome. Para incluir várias pessoas o Json correto seria este abaixo.

```
{
Casa:'b32',
integrantes:[
    {pessoa: 'joao'},
    {pessoa: 'Maria'},
    {pessoa: 'Daniel'}
 ]
}
```

Segue exemplo no shell do mongodb:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]